# In El Capitan: Safari wiped the extension database?

Tags: safari, macos

I recently did a clean install of El Capitan & added Tampermonkey to my Safari. I added a few scripts in the morning and went to sleep. I woke up at night and got back to my Safari only to learn that all the scripts in Tampermonkey had disappeared into the ether.

When I re-added a script, this is what Tampermonkey told me:

> Tampermonkey detected inconsistencies that indicate that your browser wiped the extension database!

Is there a way to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and I was preparing to ask:

- Where, on disk, does Tampermonkey for Safari store user data e.g. scripts?

Your question seems to answer my question!

(I had used fseventer to monitor file system activity whilst installing a script, but nothing conclusive was observed.)

In my case I assume that Tampermonkey dataloss resulted from an uninstall, followed by a reinstall, of various extensions.

#### Background

Two sets of answers to frequently asked questions:

- http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php
- https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78

The Tampermonkey forum is limited, seeking *Safari* finds nothing:

> The following words in your search query were ignored because they are too common words: safari …

http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q106 explains how to export scripts, but I never imagined that losing (or removing) the database of *extensions* would also lose *user data* associated with any extension.